# Pass array from Express to client's JavaScript through Handlebars template

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm passing an array of strings:
`const questionTypes = ['NUMERIC_OPEN', 'TEXT_OPEN', 'SINGLE_CHOICE', 'MULTI_CHOICE']`
from *express.js* router while rendering a view:

```
router.get('/admin', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // some code
        // ...
        return res.render('admin', { questionTypes })
    } catch (error) {
        //error handling
    }
})
```

On the `admin.hbs` I'm trying to access that array and pass it to the client's Javascript code:

```
<script>
    var questionTypes = '{{ questionTypes }}'
</script>
```

Now, when I'm accessing it from the javascript code it appears as string: `"NUMERIC_OPEN,TEXT_OPEN,SINGLE_CHOICE,MULTI_CHOICE"`, apparently because *node.js* performs toString() on view arguments while rendering HTML.

1. On the client side I can do `questionTypes.split(',')` to get the array back to it's original form but it feels like performing double work.
2. If this way doesn't work: `'{{ questionTypes }}'`, maybe there are built in Handlebars helpers that can pass actual array to the javascript although, still, it's a double work...
3. Is my way to render a view and to pass data to the client's js  correct?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, I'm getting: `"Parse error on line 105:
...tionTypes = {{ JSON.stringify(questionTy
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'"`
Although if I implement a helper which returns `JSON.stringify` on array - it works, but again I need to convert it back to array with `JSON.parse` which takes me back to 'double work'...